# Why i get timed out when i try connect in the ec2 using SSH (using browser and ssh in my pc)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I connected to ssh remotely and did all the server setup, but then when I tried to connect to do some things, I started getting the "timed out" error.

Example using browser:

[image: Time out]

In "Security Groups", the ports are correctly configured, including an SSH with "MyIp" in source:

[image: Security group]

And the instance is running normally, i can access my back-end etc. And the status is `running`

PS: i also restarted the instance etc.

Comment: That error looks like it's from EC2 instance connect, not ssh. have you tried using a standard SSH client?

Comment: @jordanm yes, browser and ssh (openssh i think) in my pc. Both get error, in my pc get connection timed out.

Comment: Are you saying that you can access it via port 80, but just not SSH? Did you temporarily try opening the Security Group for port 22 to `0.0.0.0/0` to see if it works?

Comment: the problem was ufw, the config has enabled only for nginx